# Why ng-click doesn't trigger action while ng-click-active is set though

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-click

I've got this really weird issue, coming from nowhere, where the ng-click no longer triggers action.

See generated content from the browser as follows. I see the hg-click-active that tells the tap is taken into account. togglemenu() is the controller scope method.

Last note: this work on Safari Mac, but does not on iPad iOS7 (7.1.1 actually).

The issue hits the two ng-clicks, no alert() is opened. ng-enter works.

Any idea? Any path to follow?

[EDIT 1] alert() is a scope method in my code. I have the feeling that it is not the right. Is there a way to check this?

```
<nav id="navBarHome" class="ng-scope">
        <table>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td class="bigmacButton toggleMenu" style="vertical-align: top; padding-top: 10px">
                        <div ng-click="alert('tapped'); toggleMenu()" class="ng-click-active"></div>
                    </td>
                    <td class="keynoteButton off" style="vertical-align: top;" ng-hide="getPage()=='/settings'" ng-class="{on:config.keynote, off:!config.keynote}">
                        <div ng-click="alert('tapped'); config.keynote=!config.keynote"></div>
                    </td>

                    <td style="width:150px">
                    </td>

                    <td style="width:40%">
                        <input style="width:80%" ng-model="search.keyword" size="70" type="search" results="5" placeholder="symptôme, maladie, etc." ng-enter="openPage('search')" class="ng-pristine ng-valid">
                    </td>

                    <td style="width:215px; padding-right:20px" ng-click="openPage('corporate')">
                        <img id="service" style="width:215px" src="rsc/home/Service.png">
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </nav>
```

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle or plunkr?

Comment: Hard to reproduce in an isolated example. Still trying… Is there a way to invoque plain javascript function so that tI can call javascript alert instead of my main controller alert method? I just want to make sure it's (or not) a scope issue. @Raghav

Answer (score 0):

1. You need not add `ng-click-active` to element. The CSS class
   `ng-click-active` is set by the directive while the element is being
   held down (by a mouse click or touch) so you can restyle the
   depressed element if you wish. see [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngTouch/directive/ngClick)
2. JavaScript expressions and native functions like `parseInt`, `alert`
   will not run inside angular expressions.

   ```
   ng-* = "angular_expression_only"
   ```

   See [Angular Expressions vs. JavaScript Expressions](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression)

   This won't work:

   ```
   ng-click="alert('tapped'); toggleMenu()"
   ```

   This will work:

   ```
   ng-click="my()"

   // in your controller
   $scope.my = function() {
       alert('tapped');
       toggleMenu();
   }
   ```

Comment: As the question told, this is the GENERATED dom, not what I've programmed. And the alert() is a method of te scope. @Raghav